# Spring Boot and plain html

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot

Does anyone tuned spring boot to use as a view plain html without thymeleaf? 
Here is my configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebUi extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }


        @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
//
//    @Override
//    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
//        configurer.enable();
//    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebUi.class, args);
    }
}
```

I've tried with enabling DefaultServletHandler and without. The html file placed in src/main/resources/WEB-INF/login.html and assembled. I see it in the classpath in debug. But request to http://localhost:8080/login returns 404.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One hint that might help: install actuator and open /mappings

Comment: Thanks, @Marged. I see the endpoint. I suppose the problem is not in controller layer. Something wrong with view..

Comment: Running via embedded tomcat server or using an external app server?

Comment: Remove all annotations, only leave `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: @KarthikPrasad via embedded

Answer (score 0):

Remove all annotations only leave `@SpringBootApplication`.

Remove your `InternalResourceViewResolver` and simply add the following to the `application.properties`.

```
spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.view.suffix=.html
```

Your current application class interferes with the Spring Boot auto configuration due to the `@EnableWebMvc`. Next `@SpringBootApplication` already implies `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` no need to add them again.

When adding the `spring.view.*` properties Spring Boot already configures a `InternalResourceViewResolver` for you.

Basic advice here is work with the framework not around/against the framework.